# Elegant typing solution desired, typing of one parameter is a function of another

Tags: types, ocaml, gadt, static-typing

I have a somewhat complicated typing issue, at least to me.

say we have this:

```
type rr = A | AAA | BBB

type resolve_result_t = List of string list
                        | MX_records of mx_record list
                        | Srv of srv_record list
                        | Soa of soa_record
                        | Error of string
  and mx_record = { exchange : string; priority: int; }
  and srv_record = { priority: int; weight : int; port : int; name : string; }
  and soa_record = { nsname : string;
                     hostmaster: string;
                     serial : int;
                     refresh: int;
                     retry : int;
                     expire : int;
                     minttl : int; }


let resolve ?(rr_type=A) ~host (f : (resolve_result_t -> unit) : unit = 
match rr_type with 
| A -> 
  let g = fun raw -> f (List (raw |> some_string_list_func))
  ...code that uses g
| BBB -> 
  let g = fun raw -> f (MX_records (raw |> some_mx_record_list_func))
...
```

then in caller's code we have to do stuff like this:

```
resolve ~host:"google.com" begin function 
  List l -> .. code that uses l | _ -> assert false (* Or deal with the warning *)
end
```

or

```
resolve ~rr_type:BBB ~host:"google.com" begin function 
  MX_records l -> ...similiar to previous example.
```

Even though those other cases can never occur since the typing of the function depends on the typing of another parameter.

I keep thinking there's some type system trick or usage of GADTs, but I'm never sure entirely when I need to reach for those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type _ rr =
  | A : string list rr
  | AAA : srv_record list rr
  | BBB : mx_record list rr

and _ resolve_result_t =
  | List : string list -> string list resolve_result_t
  | MX_records : mx_record list -> mx_record list resolve_result_t
  | Srv : srv_record list -> srv_record list resolve_result_t
  | Soa : soa_record list -> soa_record list resolve_result_t
  | Error : string -> string resolve_result_t

and mx_record  = { exchange : string; mx_priority: int; }

and srv_record = { srv_priority: int; weight : int; port : int; name : string; }

and soa_record = { nsname : string;
                   hostmaster: string;
                   serial : int;
                   refresh: int;
                   retry : int;
                   expire : int;
                   minttl : int; }

let resolve : type a. a rr -> string -> (a resolve_result_t -> unit) -> unit =
  fun rr_type host f ->
    match rr_type with
    | A -> f (List ["123"])
    | AAA -> f (Srv [{srv_priority=1;weight=1;port=1;name="123"}])
    | BBB -> f (MX_records [{exchange="123"; mx_priority=1}])

let () =
  let f = fun (List l) -> () in
  resolve A "google.com" f
```

In the above code, I assume when you want to use `A`, `AAA`, `BBB`, only `List`, `Srv`, and `MX_records` will show up, respectively. Pattern matching in last three lines is exhaustive thanks to GADT.

Also, note that, in `mx_record` and `srv_record`, you would like to name two `priority`s differently, otherwise you'll get a warning (related to subtyping and type definition shadowing: `{priority=1}` will always have type `srv_record`)

Update:

As for your requirement that `f` in `resolve` should also handle `Error`, 
here is another try.

```
type _ rr =
  | A : string list rr
  | AAA : srv_record list rr
  | BBB : mx_record list rr

and _ resolve_result_t =
  | List : string list -> string list resolve_result_t
  | MX_records : mx_record list -> mx_record list resolve_result_t
  | Srv : srv_record list -> srv_record list resolve_result_t
  | Soa : soa_record list -> soa_record list resolve_result_t
  | Error : string -> string resolve_result_t

and 'a rrt =
  | Ok of 'a resolve_result_t
  | Err of string resolve_result_t

and mx_record  = { exchange : string; mx_priority: int; }

and srv_record = { srv_priority: int; weight : int; port : int; name : string; }

and soa_record = { nsname : string;
                   hostmaster: string;
                   serial : int;
                   refresh: int;
                   retry : int;
                   expire : int;
                   minttl : int; }

let resolve : type a. a rr -> string -> (a rrt -> unit) -> unit =
  fun rr_type host f ->
    match rr_type with
    | A -> f (Ok (List ["123"]))
    | AAA -> f (Ok (Srv [{srv_priority=1;weight=1;port=1;name="123"}]))
    | BBB -> f (Ok (MX_records [{exchange="123"; mx_priority=1}]))

let () =
  let f = function
    | Ok (List l) -> ()
    | Err (Error s) -> print_endline s in
  resolve A "google.com" f
```

GADT-heavy code is much more complicated to write. A few more `_ -> assert false` won't hurt.

Comment: Thank you, will try out now. What intuition did you have that let you know to use GADT?

Comment: That is the way I know to build up relationship between different type constructor. I don't know if any other GADT trick that can satisfy your requirement. I would like to see other people's answer.

Comment: imho the key is to figure out a way to build up an equality relationship. In this particular case, ``type a. a rr -> string -> (a resolve_result_t -> unit) -> unit`` restricts ``a`` in ``a rr`` the same as ``a`` in ``a resolve_result_t``. Then, you modify your type definition for ``rr`` and ``resolve_result_t`` accordingly.

Comment: 1) What about the case when the there's an error and I want to give back the Error constructor? in `  let f = fun (List l) -> () in` there's no change of it handling error. 2) I want to also use named parameters but having trouble in `let resolve : type a. a rr -> string -> (a resolve_result_t -> unit) -> unit =` such that the first and second parameters are named.

Comment: Nvm, figured out named parameters.

Comment: Ah, and is it the case that GADTs must always be the first param?

Comment: here's what I thought would work:   let rr_type_of_string : type a. string -> a rr =
    fun s -> match s with
    | "A" -> A |

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94877/discussion-between-objmagic-and-edgar-aroutiounian).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the use case. If you just wish to emulate ad-hoc polymorphism (to use the same function name `resolve` with different argument types), the solution, suggested by @objmagic, will work. But, I would rather use three separate functions: `resolve_a`, `resolve_aaa` and `resolve_bbb`. This will keep type definitions much simpler and easy to read.

But if `A`, `AAA` and `BBB` tags are needed to run resolution for, say, a list of requests, I would suggest using existential wrapper.

The same GADT definitions:

```
type _ rr =
  | A : string list rr
  | AAA : srv_record list rr
  | BBB : mx_record list rr

and _ resolve_result_t =
  | List : string list -> string list resolve_result_t
  | MX_records : mx_record list -> mx_record list resolve_result_t
  | Srv : srv_record list -> srv_record list resolve_result_t
  | Soa : soa_record list -> soa_record list resolve_result_t
  | Error : string -> string resolve_result_t

and 'a rrt =
  | Ok of 'a resolve_result_t
  | Err of string resolve_result_t

and mx_record  = { exchange : string; mx_priority: int; }

and srv_record = { srv_priority: int; weight : int; port : int; name : string; }

and soa_record = { nsname : string;
                   hostmaster: string;
                   serial : int;
                   refresh: int;
                   retry : int;
                   expire : int;
                   minttl : int; }
```

Then we need to introduce existential wrapper to do type erasure

```
type handler = Handler : 'a rr * ('a rrt -> unit) -> handler
```

and pattern match on it

```
let resolve ~host = function
  | Handler (A, f) -> f (Ok (List []))
  | Handler (AAA, f) -> f (Ok (Srv [{srv_priority = 1; weight = 1; port = 1; name="123"}]))
  | Handler (BBB, f) -> f (Ok (MX_records [{exchange = "123"; mx_priority = 1}]))
```

See, you don't even need to type annotate this function!

And finally, we can run resolution for a list of requests like this

```
let () =
  let on_a = function
    | Ok (List l) -> print_endline "List"
    | Err (Error s) -> print_endline s
  and on_aaa = function
    | Ok (Srv l) -> print_endline "Srv"
    | Err (Error s) -> print_endline s
  and on_bbb = function
    | Ok (MX_records l) -> print_endline "MX_records"
    | Err (Error s) -> print_endline s
  in
  ["google.com", Handler(A, on_a);
   "google.com", Handler(AAA, on_aaa);
   "google.com", Handler(BBB, on_bbb)]
  |> ListLabels.iter ~f:(fun (host, handler) -> resolve ~host handler)
```

Comment: Hmm, but my example was just three constructor, I actually have 7, meaning i'd have to write 7 functions as well =/

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian IMHO you would just change 7 matches for 7 functions (e.g. in Haskell these 7 matches very similar to 7 functions syntactically). As I understand, both variants are more or less equivalent, because `resolve` function doesn't exhibit polymorphic behavior. It just unites 7 specializations for 7 different types. But, using simple ADT instead of GADT improve code readability a lot. I still vote for separate functions.